# Using the res.cls LaTeX file, how do I centre the address?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, cv, resume

Right now, it would look something like this for the address area: [image]

Obviously the last line is not centred, but I'd like it to be. Here's the code so far:

```
% LaTeX resume using res.cls
\documentclass[11pt]{res} % default is 10 pt
%\usepackage{helvetica} % uses helvetica postscript font (download helvetica.sty)
%\usepackage{newcent}   % uses new century schoolbook postscript font 
\usepackage{latexsym}   % to get the \Box symbol
\setlength{\textheight}{10in} % increase text height to fit resume on 1 page
\topmargin=-0.5in % start text higher on the page

\begin{document} 

\name{ANDREW J. MALONE} 
\address{739 Mill Grove Drive \\  Audubon, PA 19403 \\  (215) 555-2216}
```

It uses the `res.cls` file that is used for resume development. What would I modify to centre that?

Answer (score 5):

If you want the entire `\opening` to be centred, then the following redefinition of `\@tablebox` works:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@tablebox#1{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}#1\end{tabular}}
\makeatother
```

The original `\@tablebox` used a `l`eft-aligned column:

[image]

```
%\let\latexnofiles\nofiles % If you're using references in your resume
%\let\nofiles\relax % See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94528/5764
\documentclass[11pt]{res} % default is 10 pt
%\usepackage{helvetica} % uses helvetica postscript font (download helvetica.sty)
%\usepackage{newcent}   % uses new century schoolbook postscript font
\usepackage{latexsym}   % to get the \Box symbol
\setlength{\textheight}{10in} % increase text height to fit resume on 1 page
\topmargin=-0.5in % start text higher on the page

\makeatletter
\def\@tablebox#1{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}#1\end{tabular}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\name{ANDREW J.\ MALONE}
\address{739 Mill Grove Drive \\  Audubon, PA 19403 \\  (215) 555-2216}
\opening
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you wish to have a left-aligned address with your name, use

```
\makeatletter
\def\@tablebox#1{%
  \setbox9=\hbox{\namefont\@name}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\wd9}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}#1\end{tabular}}
\makeatother
```

This is a very particular solution to your current setup. A more general solution would be required where the name length and font size could vary. However, without more detail, this should be sufficient.

[image]

```
%\let\latexnofiles\nofiles % If you're using references in your resume
%\let\nofiles\relax % See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94528/5764
\documentclass[11pt]{res} % default is 10 pt
%\usepackage{helvetica} % uses helvetica postscript font (download helvetica.sty)
%\usepackage{newcent}   % uses new century schoolbook postscript font
\usepackage{latexsym}   % to get the \Box symbol
\setlength{\textheight}{10in} % increase text height to fit resume on 1 page
\topmargin=-0.5in % start text higher on the page

\makeatletter
\def\@tablebox#1{%
  \setbox9=\hbox{\namefont\@name}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\wd9}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}}#1\end{tabular}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\name{ANDREW J.\ MALONE}
\address{739 Mill Grove Drive \\  Audubon, PA 19403 \\  (215) 555-2216}
\opening
\end{document}
```

---

On a side note: [`res`](http://ctan.org/pkg/res) removes the capability to use references within your document. See [Problem using `etaremune` (reversing the labels of items in a list)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94528/5764) for an associated problem and fix for this.

Also, there is no particular need to use the `res` class for creating a resume. It is possible to use the default `article` class to replicate the layout, yet have some additional freedom in terms of the layout. Moreover, [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) provides a stylish take on resumes as well.