# Problem using etaremune (reversing the labels of items in a list)

Tags: lists

I am using the `etaremune` package to have the labels decreasing instead of increasing. I am writing my CV and would like to put reversing numbers for my publications. For some reason, when I create a list using `\begin{etaremune}`, the labeling of the items is not affected and remains increasing instead of decreasing. The following is the preamble of my CV document. In the document I used the `res` style file which can be found in this [link](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~paciorek/res.cls).

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth]{subfig}
\usepackage{etaremune}

\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in

\newenvironment{list1}{
  \begin{list}{\ding{113}}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in} 
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.17in}}}{\end{list}}
\newenvironment{list2}{
  \begin{list}{$\bullet$}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in} 
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{1em}}}{\end{list}}

\hypersetup{pdfauthor = {AF}, colorlinks = true, urlcolor = blue, bookmarks = false}
```

I can overcome this problem by providing the starting label such as the following:

```
\section{\sc Peer-reviewed publications}    
\begin{etaremune}[leftmargin=0pt, start=34]
....
....
\end{etaremune}
```

If I remove `start=34`, the labeling becomes increasing: 1, 2, ..., 34.

What could be the problem? Is there a better package for reversing the labeling of a list? Could someone please help me?

Comment: You need to compile your document at least twice to get the reverse numbering if you don't provide a start. (Otherwise how can LaTeX know how many you had?)  Did you do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The class `res.cls` issues `\nofiles`, which means that `etaremune` can't write off the last value in the `.aux` file.

Either remove the `\nofiles` from `res.cls` or call it as

```
\let\latexnofiles\nofiles
\let\nofiles\relax
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
```

and use `\latexnofiles` if you ever need it in such a document.

In my opinion issuing `\nofiles` in the class is a *very bad* idea; for instance, `hyperref` will have a hard time in doing its business.

Comment: Does `\nofiles` revert its writing to the `.log`?

Comment: Thank you all for your quick replies. @egres: I removed `\nofiles` and now it works flawlessly.