# How do I make email address centered under the contact information in the address?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, resume

```
\documentclass[margin]{res} 
\textwidth=5.2in % increase textwidth to get smaller right margin
\begin{document} 

\name{{Ccccc Habcdefghijkl}} % the \\[12pt] adds a blank line after name
\address{2586 12th Ave SE \\ Dfhij Lmno, TX 23456 \\ (111) 111-1111\\ abcdefijklmnopqrst@abcd.com }
\begin{resume}  
\section{Objective} 
To gain exposure to the 
\section{Education} 
\end{resume} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Kurt, the class comes from: http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick, but not beautiful, solution (some part of your data doubled):

```
\documentclass[margin]{res} 
\textwidth=5.2in % increase textwidth to get smaller right margin
\begin{document} 

\name{{Ccccc Habcdefghijkl}} % the \\[12pt] adds a blank line after name
\address{2586 12th Ave SE \\ Dfhij Lmno, TX 23456 Dfhij Lmno, TX 23456 \\ (111) 111-1111\\ \hfil abcdefijklmnopqrst@abcd.com }
\begin{resume}  
\section{Objective} 
To gain exposure to the 
\section{Education} 
\end{resume} 
\end{document}
```

All the work done by `\hfil` before the e-mail.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Within the [`res` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/res), the address is set in a single `l`-column `tabular`. As such, regular `tabular`-style adjustments are possible. For example, setting the email address using `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` will override the default `l`eft alignment:

```
\address{%
  2586 12th Ave SE \\
  Dfhij Lmno, TX 23456 Dfhij Lmno, TX 23456 \\
  (111) 111-1111 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{abcdefghijklmnopqrst@abcd.com}}
```

yields

[image]

For an entirely-centred address block, see [Using the res.cls LaTeX file, how do I centre the address?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94204/5764)